# how to make expanding view with autolayout?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, swift3

(I don't know english well). I have a question: can you show an example of my problem. I want to make expanding list. i.e. i have a controller view and when I click on one of strings there appears a list with data of this strong under it, and other string shift below.

Comment: You have to show what you have done. Review your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with an additional(!) constraint for the height, by which you can set the view's height to zero:

1. Define this constraint in the storyboard (or code).
2. Create an outlet property to the constraint. This must be a strong property because of deactivating a constraint will remove it from the corresponding views.
3. Give this constraint the highest priority. Other constraints which influence the hight should have smaller priorities.
4. You can now hide and show the view by activating and deactivating the constraint.

Animation of the change can be done with UIKit animations:

```
UIView *theView = self.view; // Must be a parent of the animated view

self.heightConstraint.active = isHidden;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [theView layoutIfNeeded];
}
```